# How to slide in different div with buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my code I have 2 panels. The lower panel has 3 buttons with pressing each one must load different data in the upper panel.

So lets say if i press the button 1 in the lower panel the div numbers 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 will slide in. And if I press button two, div 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4 will loads.

Here is my setup code: **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gfx67jfm/)**

```css
.panel {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.panel > .panelTop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 49px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
}
.panel > .panelBottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
.panel > .panelTop > div {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  float: right;
  margin: 13px 9px 0 0;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
.panel > .panelBottom > div {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  float: right;
  margin: 9px 9px 0 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <div class="panelTop">
    Dependant Buttons:
    <!-- Side1 -->
    <div>1.1</div>
    <div>1.2</div>
    <div>1.3</div>

    <!-- Side2
    <div>2.1</div>
    <div>2.2</div>
    <div>2.3</div> -->

    <!-- Side3 
    <div>3.1</div>
    <div>3.2</div>
    <div>3.3</div> -->
  </div>
  <div class="panelBottom">
    Main Buttons:
    <div class="btn1">1</div>
    <div class="btn2">2</div>
    <div class="btn3">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Each div will have their unique classes, so I am not sure if I can achieve it with arrays in jQuery or `visibility: hidden` in CSS.

Any ideas ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this?

**EDIT:** [Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/zeevkatz/oub8fh9w/)

*Only you need to do is CSS "manipulation" (**no JS at all**).

I write this:

**html**

```
<div class="panel">
  <div class="panelTop">
    Dependant Buttons:
    <div>
      <input id="box-1" name="trigger" type="radio">
      <div>1.1</div>
      <div>1.2</div>
      <div>1.3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="box-2" name="trigger" type="radio">
      <div>2.1</div>
      <div>2.2</div>
      <div>2.3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="box-3" name="trigger" type="radio">
      <div>3.1</div>
      <div>3.2</div>
      <div>3.3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panelBottom">
    Main Buttons:
    <label for="box-1" class="btn1">1</label>
    <label for="box-2" class="btn2">2</label>
    <label for="box-3" class="btn3">3</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
input[type="radio"]{
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

.panelTop > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 0;
}

.panelTop > div div {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: ease .3s;
  transform: translate(-150%, 0)
}

.panelTop > div input[type="radio"]:checked ~ div {
   opacity: 1;
   transform: translate(0%, 0)
}

.panel {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.panel > .panelTop {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 49px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
}

.panel > .panelBottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.panel > .panelTop > div div {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  float: right;
  margin: 0px 9px 0 0;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}

.panel > .panelBottom > div {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  float: right;
  margin: 9px 9px 0 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

You can see that every `label` tag have `for` attr within `id` of your radio input type.

The `label` tags "trigger" your radio inputs and with **CSS** selectors we can change the divs after them.

```
.panelTop > div input[type="radio"]:checked ~ div
```

This **CSS** selector represents whats happen after the click, so you can change it whatever you want.

**`input[type="radio"]:checked ~ div`** - get every div after checked radio input type.

I hope this example help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's what i am looking for, but yes I just need to show only one group. So if button 2 is pressed all disappear except 2.1, 2.2, 2.3. Also I would really appreciate if you let me know how I can implement so animation that buttons either fade or slide in. Thanks again

Comment: This is not a self contained answer nd therefore is of very little long term value. Answers should stand on their own and demos only be used to support what is actually in the answer

Comment: Thank you. I do appreciate your effort and time. Although other answers did the job correctly but yours seem the most efficient one. Quality of code!

Answer (score 0):

I have done some updation in @zeev katz code.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/02usnvq7/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().siblings().find("input").prop("checked", false);l
});
```

});

Review it.
Hope you will like it :)